# Is the laravelshoppingcart package compatible with laravel 7?

Tags: php, laravel-7

I am using an installation of laravel 7.x but I am trying to install the package **laravelshoppingcart** with compose like this : composer `require "darryldecode/cart` but I have an error.

```
 Problem 1
    - Installation request for gloudemans/shoppingcart ^2.6 -> satisfiable by gloudemans/shoppingcart[2.6.0].
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v7.9.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
- don't install illuminate/support v5.4.19|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.27|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.36|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.9|don't install laravel/framework v7.9.2
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v7.9.2, required as ^7.0) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.9.2].
```

Comment: Bonjour, Stackoverflow est un site strictement anglophone. Veuillez, s'il-vous-plait, traduire votre question en anglais, afin que l'on puisse vous aider convenablement.

Comment: ok sorry for revise and i come back

Answer (score 0):

So I read that the package is not up to date for version 7 of laravel: we must therefore give the developer time to update.